# Pass powerhell output to command to uninstall Google Chrome

Tags: powershell

I have this command to get the uninstall string;

```
Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall, HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall `
 | Get-ItemProperty | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -match "Chrome" } | Select-Object -Property DisplayName, UninstallString
```

Output;

```
DisplayName   UninstallString
-----------   ---------------
Google Chrome MsiExec.exe /X{943D3AC3-A94D-3ADE-B875-6CBB57908A35}
```

I can then uninstall with;

```
MsiExec.exe /X{943D3AC3-A94D-3ADE-B875-6CBB57908A35} /qn /norestart
```

I would like to know how to do this in a oner like with bash (I am new to Powershell).

Basically pass the output to the command to uninstall

Comment: I commend to your attention [Microsoft Docs on `Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.1). There is also the possibility that you might find [Microsoft Docs on `Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-7.1) to be of use, but the latter is not recommended.

Comment: You should always try to "do your homework" first, and describe what you have tried, or focus on a specific issue that you don't understand. This is a question that very likely could have been answered with a bit of effort on a web search; without doing your own due diligence first, you risk the question being ignored (or, in some cases, closed).

Comment: I came here after Googling and cannot find the answer, hence the question

Comment: That's OK - but you should indicate what you searched for and what, if anything you found (and why it didn't work). I happened to have those two commands right "on top" of my head (because I use them frequently), but as an experiment, I tried [asking Google ***powershell run command from string***](https://www.google.com/search?q=powershell+run+command+from+string) and found answers, including some right here on [SO].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can uninstall in powershell with this since it's an msi install (powershell 5.1):

```
get-package *chrome* | uninstall-package
```

or this since the version number isn't in the name:

```
uninstall-package 'google chrome'
```